# How can I get a transparent game window in Unity using Universal Render Pipeline (URP)?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, urp

In the past, in Unity, you could use DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea in Unity to get a transparent game window drawn on top of the desktop, making all game objects appear on the desktop itself. This was done using the legacy render pipeline.

Reference: https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-windows-transparent-window-with-opaque-contents-lwa_colorkey.323057/page-2

Now, I have an app built in URP and I'd like to achieve the same effect but have no clue how to do it. Downgrading to legacy render pipeline is not really an option as it is legacy at this point.

Anyone know how to achive a transparent game window drawn on top of the desktop using URP? If it helps, I only need it to work in Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.unity.com/threads/window-as-transparent-overlay-not-working-since-2018-3-0b12.593653/ Haven't tried but I thought window transparency was done through external windows calls, which probably still function with URP

Answer (score 1):

Edit -> Player Settings -> Player -> Resolution and Presentation -> UNCHECK `Use DXGI Flip Model Swapchain for D3D11`

It is checked by default in URP projects, and it breaks up the WinAPI hack you mention in your post.